# VS 2010 .dll.refresh is in TFS but not .dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a Web site project open from TFS. When I expand the files related to one dll, it shows that the .dll.refresh is under source control, but the plain .dll is not. If I right-click on the .dll there is no option to "Add to Source Control". How can I add it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the dll files from the bin folder.  The .refresh files are text files which tell the aspnet compiler where to copy the dll files from.  Open the .refresh files to see where it expects to find the dlls and manually add them from that location.  Visual Studio will want to exclude them so using the Source Control Explorer window click the "add files" icon and in the dialog box that appears select the "excluded" page and include the dlls.

Make sure you add the dll folder(s) to the build workspaces if you're using builds.